# identifying admins from mentions discordjs

Tags: discord.js

I want to find out if there are mentions in a message which I am doing using `if(message.mentions.users.first())` but now among all the mentions I also want to filter out mentions of the admin team and not those of the community members.  How to achieve that?

I tried filtering users based on roles like this

```
   let r = [];
   message.mentions.users.forEach( user => {
        console.log('user' + user)
        user.roles.forEach(role => {
            console.log('role' + role)
            r.push(role);
        }) 
        console.log('roles' + r);
        var member = false;
        for (i in r) {
            if (i == 'admin') {
                member = true;
            }
        }
    })
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Just filter the mentions collection to members who have only a certain role, or permission, depending on what you mean by admin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const adminName = ['<role name>'];
const adminId = ['<role ID>'];

client.on('message', (msg) => {
  let admins = msg.mentions.members.filter( (user) => {
    return adminId.some(id => user.roles.has(id)) || user.roles.some(r => adminName.includes(r.name));
  });
  console.log(admins.map(d => d.user.username));
});
```

There, I created 2 arrays, one with the role ID and another with the role name. You can use both, or only one (I prefer to use the id, because you can change a role name, but you can't change an id, except if you delete the role).

Then, I iterate through the [`members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members) in the mentions of the messages. Why the `members` and not the `users`? Because the `GuildMember` is a type linked to a guild, which is an instance of an user in a guild, and so it has the role of the user.

Then I check if one of the id of my admins roles is in the roles of the user **or** if one of the roles name is inside my `adminName`.

The variable `admins` is a collection of `GuildMember`.

You can change the function inside the `some` to match whatever condition make someone an admin for you.

Comment: This works fine. However, my requirements change and for that, the solution I used is that I made a json object of memberids and mapped it to the data I wanted to get for each admin member. Still, I'll accept this answer as this provides the necessary solution and great insight.